Unable to connect to postgres database outside of docker image
I started to dabble with docker. I have a asp .net core application. I can go to my route /health and see my app can connect to my postgres server fine. But the moment I deploy my application to a container and run it locally, it is unable to connect to that database.
I tried exposing port 5432 in Dockerfile but that didn't assist in anyway.  The error I got is Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xxxx:5432
I was wondering if I can get any assistance in how to connect to my remote pg server from my container.
When I telnet from my container, it's unable to reach the server. But telnet works from from my machine
I can telnet to my sql server from container but not to my postgres server

Have you forward the port when you launch the container with the -p flag ?

I have not. @TinouHD may I ask how would I do that? I can see postgres is 5432

Yeah i think this would do the job. The EXPOSE directive in the docker file doesn't publish the ports when you launch a container.

So are you suggesting to EXPOSE 5432? You also wrote "doesn't" publish the ports

You may be able to add --network=host to your docker run command.
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#network

Thank you for the answer, unfortunately still times out!

The EXPOSE directive in the Dockerfile doesn't publish the specified port.
Dockerfile reference

The EXPOSE instruction doesn't actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container [...]

So, to publish the port you can use the -p option which take in option the port mapping you want between host and container.
docker run ... -p 4444:5432/tcp postgres

This will bind the port 4444 on the host to the port 5432 in the container.
You can use any unused port on the host.

You can also use the -P option that publish every exposed port. (With this method you can not choose the host port yourself.)
docker run ... -P postgres

This will bind the exposed port 5432 from the container to the host.
